# Different \marginparwidth's for title page and part pages with scrbook

Tags: marginpar, scrbook

I would like to widen the outer margin of my book to make more room for side notes. In addition, the page footer should span the entire width of the text and the margin. Changes should be local to the table of contents and chapters, that is the page layouts of the title page and part pages should be left intact.

I have already managed to construct a minimal working example. However, the solution is not practical (nor neat), since, for example, one must insert `\full` before and `\margin` after every new part. Could this be automated?

My attempts with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` led nowhere i.e.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startpart}{\full}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\margin}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

didn't produce the desired output.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\BeforeRestoreareas{\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\storeareas\full

\newlength{\addition}\setlength{\addition}{3cm} % for example
\areaset[-.5\addition]{\textwidth-\addition}{\textheight}
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=textwithmarginpar}
\storeareas\margin

\full

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\margin

\tableofcontents

\full

\addpart{First part}

\margin

\blinddocument

\full

\addpart{Second part}

\margin

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could patch `\partheadstartvskip` and `\partheademptypage`

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically

\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\BeforeRestoreareas{\clearpage}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \storeareas\full
  %
  \newlength{\addition}\setlength{\addition}{3cm} % for example
  \areaset[-.5\addition]{\textwidth-\addition}{\textheight}%
  \KOMAoptions{footwidth=textwithmarginpar}%
  \storeareas\margin
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\partheadstartvskip{\full}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\partheademptypage{\margin}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xpretocmd\maketitle{\full}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xapptocmd\maketitle{\margin}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\addpart{First part}
\blinddocument
\addpart{Second part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply re-defining the commands `\addpart` and `\tableofcontents` does the trick:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\BeforeRestoreareas{\clearpage}
\newlength{\addition}\setlength{\addition}{3cm} % for example

\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
\areaset[-.5\addition]{\textwidth-\addition}{\textheight}
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=textwithmarginpar}

\oldtoc

\typearea{current}%
}

\let\oldaddpart\addpart
\renewcommand{\addpart}[1]{%
\typearea{current}

\oldaddpart{#1}

\areaset[-.5\addition]{\textwidth-\addition}{\textheight}
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=textwithmarginpar}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\addpart{First part}

\blinddocument

\addpart{Second part}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```